# Keyboard for general use and gaming

Tags: gaming, keyboards

I'm looking to get a new keyboard ([and a mouse, too](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1797/968)). It'll likely be used for 5-8 hours a day for the foreseeable future, mainly for web browsing, programming, and gaming. I am mainly looking for something that will work *well* for gaming without necessarily having fancy features like macros and programmable backlighting.

The keyboard can be in a combo with a mouse, as long as the mouse fits [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1797/968).

#### Requirements

- Cheap (**under $20-$30USD**, depending on how many of my preferred features it meets)
- Works with **Windows 10**
- **Not wireless** (unless the batteries are going to last years on one charge)
- **Less than 19 inches** wide (any larger and it won't fit)
- **Decent rollover** (I can't exactly quantify this as I still haven't figured out exactly how rollover works, but as an example of "decent" I'd need it to register e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, and <kbd>Space</kbd> at the same time)
- Enough **backlighting** that I can distinguish the keys in low light conditions (this is the main problem with my current keyboard)

#### Preferred features

Listed in approximate order of importance

- **Relatively quiet** (I'm often on the computer when the rest of the house is asleep, and I don't want to be annoying)
- Any **lighting can be turned on and off**
- Any **lighting is green** to go with my headset (really doesn't matter; I'm willing to pay like an extra $1 for this)

#### Not necessary

- Extraneous features like **macros, dynamic backlighting**, etc.
- **A number pad** (I do occasionally use my current one, but it takes up so much extra space... I still haven't decided whether or not it's worth it)

Things I have considered:

- [CM Storm Devastator](http://us.coolermaster.com/product/Detail/gaming/devastator/devastator-green.html): looks great except that it apparently has two-key rollover. I'm not sure exactly what that means, so I don't entirely know whether it would be good enough.
- [CM Storm Octane](http://us.coolermaster.com/product/Detail/gaming/octane/octane.html): good, but a little expensive, and I don't need the extra mouse buttons, dynamic lighting, or 19 key rollover
- [Logitech K120](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/k120): definitely cheap enough, three-key rollover, but doesn't have backlighting.

Answer (score 4):

In this price range I would choose:

- [CM Storm Devastator - LED Gaming Keyboard and Mouse Combo Bundle](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823129030). It is available in Newegg shop in Blue/Red LED for $29.99 and in Green LED for $41.37.

But if you can find additional funds I would recommend other keyboard and mouse:

- Keyboard: [Gigabyte Force K7](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4565#ov) which costs arond $50
- Mouse: [Roccat Lua](http://www.roccat.org/en-US/Products/Gaming-Mice/Lua/) which week ago I saw in Amazon for $20 but now it costs $35.89 (maybe it will be on sale again)

Both mouse and keyboard have better parameters than CM set and they are absolute minimum for gaming. If you are not interested in better precision and reacion times then take CM set.

Comment: The CM Storm Devastator looks good enough!

Comment: Actually I just found something that said that the keyboard has 2-key rollover, which is unacceptable for me.

Comment: Apologies for my fickleness, but I did some more research and figured out that the rollover _might_ be acceptable, but I can't tell if I haven't bought it yet.