# Mouse for general use and gaming

Tags: gaming, mice

I'm looking to get a new mouse ([and a keyboard, too](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1793/968)). It'll likely be used for 5-8 hours a day for the foreseeable future, mainly for web browsing, programming, and gaming. I am mainly looking for something that will work *well* for gaming without necessarily having fancy features like macros.

#### Requirements

- Cheap (**under $10-$15USD**, depending on how many of my preferred features it meets)
- Works with **Windows 10**
- **Not wireless** (unless the batteries are going to last years on one charge)
- **Nice scrollwheel for gaming**, i.e. it clicks nicely and doesn't have "smooth" scrolling (these are the problems with my current mouse)

#### Preferred features

Listed in approximate order of importance

- Has on-the-fly **adjustable DPI** (so I can easily make pixel-by-pixel cursor/crosshair adjustments without turning on **shudder* mouse acceleration*.)
- Any **lighting can be turned on and off**
- Any **lighting is green** to go with my headset (really doesn't matter; I'm willing to pay like an extra $1 for this)

#### Not necessary

- Extraneous features like **macros**, etc.

The mouse can be in a combo with a keyboard, as long as the keyboard fits [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1793/968).

Comment: I was going to say the Logitech g502 but that is 60 dollars and it has eleven programmable buttons. Why do you not want macros though? They can be very useful when programming at least in my opinion.

Comment: @AidenGrossman It's not that I don't want them, they're just _not necessary_. In general, extra features increase the price, and I would rarely use macros anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the [Logitech G100s](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SH30V6A). It is a cheap, no frills mouse. It has a clicky scroll wheel, and a button to choose the DPI. It has no lighting, no macros, and I find it to be suitably comfortable. The software used to select where your DPI choices are for the button to cycle through supports 1-5 different DPIs between 250 and 2500.

It is slightly more than your budget, however I feel it is a very solid offering and well worth the extra money at about $15-25 depending on where you purchase it.